# Is there a data structure in JDK that can remove, find and insert in log-N time?

Tags: java, algorithm

After testing on RDring, I found that remove element sometime fails and the
time complexity to remove a timer is linear; the alarm manager uses a TreeSet
that iterate all elements for deleting.

Then, I look source of PriorityQueue and guess maybe can use it to store timer 
list. But I am very surprised that, though the deleting in PriorityQueue is in 
constant time, the inserting of an element in Priority queue is also linear. 
They didn't use any tree or something binary search technique to speed up the 
insertion.

If I want to remove fast, then PQ but insert slow. Otherwise I can use TreeSet
for insert in log-N but delete slow. Is there any tree or heap that support 
both insert, delte and find in log-N speed ?

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to know complexity of various data structure in JDK. The url seems only describe data structure's complexity.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any tree or heap that support both insert, delete and find in log-N speed ?

Yes, the Red-Black tree based [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) guarantees that:

> **Class TreeMap<K,V>**
>
> ...
>
> This implementation provides guaranteed **log(n) time cost** for the containsKey, **get, put and remove** operations. Algorithms are adaptations of those in Cormen, Leiserson, and Rivest's Introduction to Algorithms.

See also

- [What are the time complexities of various data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294634/what-are-the-time-complexities-of-various-data-structures) for a good overview of time complexities of various data structures. The complexity of the respective Java implementations are usually documented in the corresponding JavaDoc.
- [Java Collections – Performance (Time Complexity)](http://infotechgems.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/java-collections-performance-time.html) has a good overview of the JDK container classes.

By the way, you say that with `TreeSet`, delete is slow - however, the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) also documents `O(log(n))` for delete:

> **Class TreeSet<E>**
>
> ...
>
> This implementation provides guaranteed **log(n) time cost** for the basic operations (add, **remove** and contains).

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to know complexity of various data structure in JDK. The url seems only describe data structure's complexity.

Comment: Right - usually, the complexity of the respective java implementations are documented in their JavaDocs, as in the TreeMap JavaDoc I linked. Adjusted my answer.